# Flask-SQLAlchemy: sqlite3 IntegrityError

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating an application to replace current tab managers in the browser. I've created a simple one-to-many relationship between groups - table Topic, and tabs - table Tab. I want to be able to automatically delete topic's children if I delete it. This is what I currently have:

```
from flask import request, redirect, url_for, render_template, Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import exc
from flask_whooshee import Whooshee
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
whooshee = Whooshee(app)

@whooshee.register_model('topic_name')
class Topic(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    topic_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    topic_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    topic_changed = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    topic_tabs = db.relationship('Tab', backref='topic', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic')

@whooshee.register_model('tab_name', 'tab_link', 'tab_description')
class Tab(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tab'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tab_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    tab_link = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    tab_favicon = db.Column(db.String)
    tab_description = db.Column(db.String)
    tab_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    tab_changed = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    topic_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "Test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        print(str(e))
        db.session.rollback()

    top = Topic(topic_name='Test')
    db.session.add(top)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        print(str(e))
        db.session.rollback()

    top2 = Topic(topic_name='Test2')
    db.session.add(top2)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        print(str(e))
        db.session.rollback()

    t1 = Tab(tab_name='t1', tab_link='t1l', tab_favicon='t1f', tab_description='t1d', topic_id=top.id)
    t2 = Tab(tab_name='t2', tab_link='t2l', tab_favicon='t2f', tab_description='t2d', topic_id=top.id)
    t3 = Tab(tab_name='t3', tab_link='t3l', tab_favicon='t3f', tab_description='t3d', topic_id=top.id)

    db.session.add(t1)
    db.session.add(t2)
    db.session.add(t3)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        print(str(e))
        db.session.rollback()
    import uuid
    app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The problem is that I get integrity errors, when I'm trying to add something in the database and I'm not sure what can go wrong. I also want to save previous records in the database if I stop the server, how do I implement that as well?

**UPD**: the behaviour below happens even if I delete my database entirely. I get this error after simply running the script `python script_name.py` in an empty folder.

**UPD2**: if anyone needs to check whether a database exists, there is a special helper function https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database_helpers.html#database-exists

> (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: topic.topic_name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO topic (topic_name, topic_created, topic_changed) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Test', '2018-09-03 05:21:08.728564', '2018-09-03 05:21:08.728564')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
>
> (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: topic.topic_name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO topic (topic_name, topic_created, topic_changed) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Test2', '2018-09-03 05:21:08.730562', '2018-09-03 05:21:08.730562')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
>
> (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: tab.tab_link [SQL: 'INSERT INTO tab (tab_name, tab_link, tab_favicon, tab_description, tab_created, tab_changed, topic_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('t1', 't1l', 't1f', 't1d', '2018-09-03 05:21:08.733561', '2018-09-03 05:21:08.733561', None)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

Comment: The error messages are quite explicit. Apparently you already have `topic` records where `topic_name` is 'Test' resp. 'Test2' in your database. The same goes for `Tab` with a `tab_link` 't1l'. The columns in question all have a [UNIQUE constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp). There can only ever be one record with any given value in that column. If you try to insert a duplicate, your database engine will refuse the insert.

Comment: @shmee I know about that, but this happens even if I delete my database entirely. I get this error after simply running the script `python script_name.py` in an empty folder.

Comment: _After_ running `python script_name.py` or _while_ running it? Also, what is `script_name.py`? The code you posted above?

Comment: @shmee I meant while running and suprisingly the records do appear in the database. I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is the WSGI application, hence runs as `__main__`. If you use `debug=True` as argument to `app.run()` the server will start, set debug mode: on and restart `with stat`, executing the `__name__ == '__main__'` block again (and again every time you make changes to your script and save it while the server is running).

When you start your app on an empty/deleted DB, the first time the `__name__ == '__main__'` block is executed, it creates the DB and inserts the two `Topic` and three `Tab` objects you create in that block. Then it sets debug mode and restarts, again executing that block, attempting to insert these five objects a second time.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__name__)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output:

```
__main__ # <-- fist time around it creates DB and objects
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat # <-- re-executing your script
__main__ # <-- trying to create the same objects again, violating the UNIQUE constraint
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 302-544-855
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: Ok, now all the code that should run only once is in a separate global function, but it still throws this errors https://hastebin.com/evoyixuwux.py

Comment: @MikhailKrassavin Because of line 79. When restarting, the _whole_ script is executed a second time. `configure_db()` will run twice, throwing the error when the server restarted in debug mode.

Comment: Fine, I'll keep on going without debug mode, thank you