# psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "tablename" already exists, but it really doesn't exist

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I keep getting this error 
`psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "customers" already exists`
and I know what it means.

The problem is, there was really no table named "customers" when I ran the program. To make sure of it, I created a new database with no table or I double checked that there was no such table in the existing database before running the code. I added print statement to check where it clashes.

```
def createTable():
    conn = pg.connect(conn_str)
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    sql = """
    create table customers
    ( 
       ... 
    )
    """
    print("checking 1111111")                # printed
    cur.execute(sql)

    print("checking 2222222")                # not printed
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createTable() 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can get around the issue by adding `IF NOT EXISTS` to `sql` but I'm really wondering why because this is part of a code that used to work perfectly.

[edit] added what I did to make sure the table didn't exist

Comment: It worked once you had new db, and since you connect to existing db rather than create new one, you already have such table created in there... Use IF NOT EXISTS

Comment: @Kendoka It actually doesn't work for a new db or when I deleted the existing "customers" table and then run this code.

Comment: If it's sqlite try deleting db completely

Comment: It's the `debug` flag in the `app.run` call. It effectively causes the code in the `__name__ == '__main__'` block to be executed twice, raising the error during the second execution. I have elaborated on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144502/4134674) in the context of a UNIQUE constraint violation.

Comment: @shmee This seems to be the cause. Print was executed twice. Thank you.