# sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: error even though the values I'm entering are unique?

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

I have a database structured like this.

```
CREATE TABLE "work_order" ( "id" INTEGER, "ServiceTitle" TEXT UNIQUE, 
"Link" TEXT UNIQUE, "Status" TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("id") );
```

When I try enter some values I get an error.

```
"sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: work_order.Link"
```

Then the program terminates.

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Even though the value I entered into the Link column is unique.

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('WO.db', timeout=10)
 c = conn.cursor()

 c.execute("insert into work_order (ServiceTitle, Link, Status) values 
 (?,?,?)", ('oo', 'll', 'rr'))

 conn.commit()
 conn.close()
```

The new record still gets inserted to the database exactly as I wanted. I just get this error on pycharm.

I tried inserting the primary key ID also. It's not auto increment so I can enter it manually so long as it is unique.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('WO.db', timeout=10)
c = conn.cursor()

 c.execute("insert into work_order (id, ServiceTitle, Link, Status) values 
(?,?,?,?)", (7, 'kkkk', 'eeeee', 'qqqqq'))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Again I get an error in pycharm but different this time. The record still gets inserted into the database again though exactly as I wanted. The process then terminates again.

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: work_order.id

Process finished with exit code 1.
```

Any suggestions as to why I'm getting this error even though all of the values i'm entering into these columns are unique values not present in the database?

UPDATE***  I created a new table and removed the unique constraints. I now get no error but the records enter the table twice. Which is what the problem was when there was Unique constraints. I don't know why there is two records being inserted though.

Comment: Are you sure the data aren't already in the db from a previous session? Have you tried clearing the DB first? Also, try  query the count of records in the table, then try enter the data it's claiming are not unique and get your error as above, then query the count again to see if it has actually increased.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I have the database open and can see the new records coming in. I change the values every time I run it to be unique. Here is a screenshot of the data that is in there at the moment.  https://imgur.com/yMEuhRs

Comment: @Dan It appears my insert statement is happening twice. When I removed the unique constraints, two of the same records where entering the db. I'm still not sure why I'm getting two inserts.

Comment: Is Flask involved in this by any chance?

Comment: Yeah flask is involved.

Comment: Thought so :) With `debug=True` I presume. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143572/flask-sqlalchemy-sqlite3-integrityerror)